# Html div resize after putting some text

Tags: html, css

Guys.. I want my html div not to resize after putting some text..
as you can see in the picutre above is set the minimum height as 250px; but after putting some
LAYER 1
 manytime. may 20 times, im expecting that the  div height will be 250 px but it automaticaly resize? Anyone know how to set the height of the div as fix? even adding a text to it will not make the div automaticaly resize? Thank you..

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of setting minimum height as 250px, set `height` as 250px...

Comment: Thank you.. Can i use this in table?

Comment: `height` does not apply to `inline` elements. To make it work, you should wrap the table in a div and apply `height` property on the div. You may want to use `overflow: auto` for scrolling...

Answer (score 3):

set both min-height and max-height to 250

Comment: Thank you. The same with my comment on sidharth. Can i use this to table for example so that it will not automatically reize?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following; note that you'll want `overflow:hidden;` if you don't want the content to spill out of the div:

```css
div#yourid {
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/t4prR/)

Comment: @thenewbie If this answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the outlined checkmark below the down arrow.

Comment: Sorry i already accept Sidharth Mudgal answer. If i can only select two answers. But thank you for helping.

Comment: @thenewbie Tis fine, if anything, I helped you accept their answer, where you might not have known how to before.  Glad I could assist either way.